# Delete DOM generated elements without <img> inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

A lot of `.cell` elements are added to the DOM on document load. Only some of them are needed. If an `<img>` was also created within them, they are needed. If an `<img>` element was not created within the `.cell` elements, then delete the whole `.cell` element. If the `<img>` was created then do nothing.

How can I do that?

```
<div class="cell">
    <div class="a-class">
        <div class="always-generated-div"></div>
        <img> <!-- if generated --->
    </div>
 </div>
```

```js
jq(".cell img").each(function() {
    if (jq(this).length > 0) {
        console.log("Oh There You Are");
    } else { 
        console.log("Empty elements erased");
        jq( ".cell" ).remove();
    }
});
```

Comment: Why you put this condition if( jq(this).length > 0 )??? It will always be true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can select a parent by their child elements using the `:has()` selector (and the `:not()` selector in this case too). From there, you can `remove()` them. Try this:

```
$('.cell:not(:has(img))').remove();
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/vtda1jn7/)

Comment: Why not use the `not()` jQuery method?

Comment: Because `:not` works on the parent, it doesn't look at the children, assuming you mean *only* use `not()`. If you mean use the `not()` method with the `:has()` selector in that, then that would work too, this just keeps it all in one selector.

Comment: I added a working example for you. Don't forget to include jQuery in the page, and put the code in a document.ready handler.

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Comment: Is there a way no to erase them after they are created but to keep them from being added to the DOM in the first place?

Comment: I would imagine so, but it would depend on the code you use to add them to the DOM. If you start a new question with that code, I'm sure someone will be able to solve that issue too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`:empty`](https://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/) selector

> Select all elements that have no children (including text nodes).

```
jq(".cell:empty").remove()
```